# Is the phrase "on a scale of 1 to 10" used often if at all?

Tags: phrase, equivalent-phrase

Just wondering since it does seem to me like a more western phrase, in Google translate it comes out as 上规模的1到10, I'm just wondering if there is a more common way to ask someone to rate a particular thing or person in Chinese.

Comment: Off-topic, just notice your name. Nice :D

Comment: I would say `在十分制中 ...`

Comment: 以十分制打分, or simply, 请打分, 满分10分.

Comment: searching web entering e.g. "翻译 on a scale from 1 to 10"  as search term results in (more or less agreeing with above):
iciba:The patient rates the therapies on a scale of zero to ten 患者按十分制给这些治疗方法打分。
Score each criterion on a scale of 1 to 5 按1到5分给每一种标准打分。
also note nciku: on a scale of 1 to 1 从1到10各等级地

Comment: I did not hear people say `在十分制中` or `以十分制打分`. Maybe just around where I live.

Comment: 在十分制中 doesn't sound right. I agree that 按十分制打分 is more colloquial and common, 以十分制打分 sounds slightly more literacy.

Comment: Example on the use of 以十分为满分 "on a scale from 1 to 10" by  Deutsche Welle Chinese, 9/22/14 headline “可以不走的话，有谁想走？”: 
以十分为满分（表示极度乐观），香港人的平均回应仅为4.22分

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use it! =) My friends use it too. But we are immigrants who have lived in the USA for many years with fluency in both languages (we use both languages) so not sure if our English might have affected that. But, I remember hearing that phrase when I was little in China as well. We usually don't use the direct translation of "on a scale of 1 to 10", instead, we would say something like "what score would you rate X?" then we will add "on a scale of 1 to 10" to indicate the score range.

For example, girls' sleepover (elementary school!):

我喜欢陈某某， 不过打分的话， 他只有 7 分。 I like Chen X, but to give a score, he only scores a 7.

如果给他打分， 你会给他打多少分？ If you are going to give him a score, what score would he get?

1 到 10， 10 为最高分， 你会给他打多少分？ 1 to 10, 10 being the highest, what score will he get?

I don't watch Chinese entertainment shows often so I don't know if I am recalling it correctly, but (I think) you will hear a host saying something like, "please give a score for X person." --> 请给 X 打分。

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks! That's great to know. It definitely seems like a mostly western phrase

Comment: You are very welcome! I can't comment on your question in the other answer because I don't have enough "reputation" on the website (T_T). For the original answer, "如果要我给分数" by @pete-c, think of it this way, "If (you) need me to give a score." For "如果我要给分数", it is "if I need to give a score." So both sentences are correct and natural! :)

Answer (score 5):

To rate something, I would say:

(要)在十分內打個分數，(我會給六分)
On a scale of 1 to 10, (I would give it a 6.)

在十分內 = Under a score of 10, 要 is just optional.

Other ways of saying are:

1. 若要评分，我会给...(To give a score, I would give...)
2. 如果要我给分数，我会给...(If I have to rate it, I would give...)

It is not frequent in Chinese to say something like this, comparing to English. That Google translate is definitely wrong.

Comment: Thanks :) Are you using traditional Chinese btw? And would there be an alternative saying in trying to rate something or not?

Comment: Yes I am. To put it in Simplified Chinese, it would be `(要)在十分内打个分数，(我会给六分)` Other ways of saying that would be `如果要我给分数...`(`If I have to rate it...`) or `若要评分，我会给...`(`To give a score, I would give...`). Google translate is a great tool to change between traditional and simplified Chinese BTW ;)

Comment: Ha yes, I know, I used it to translate as for 会 I did not recognise the traditional character.

Comment: For 如果要我给分数, it doesn't seem to make sense to me, I would use 如果我要给分数. Can you clarify that your sentence makes sense, and does mine work too or is it me trying to use English Grammar?